# Rails Associations - has_one, belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, belongs-to, rails-models

It's been a while since I've worked with Rails (Rails 6) on a new application. I'm failing to recall how to properly set up associations. I have two problems that are rather similar and may help to answer each other. I understand that the model containing `belongs_to` will hold the foreign key, however, it feels backward in my head.

1. I have a User model with a `pronouns` attribute. I have a Model/Table `pronouns`. A user can have one pronouns record associated with is (`has_one`?). But a pronouns record can belong to any number of users. So `belongs_to` won't work in this case, since the foreign key would be on the `pronouns` table. The way that I've sort of gotten around this is to use `belongs_to`, but this doesn't feel right because I need to make it optional since `pronouns` isn't required for a user.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pronouns, optional: true
end

class Pronoun < ApplicationRecord; end
```

2. I have the following models: Location, User, Experience, JobPost. In this case, User, Experience, and JobPost can have a single location, but Location can belong_to (have_many?) of each of these. This feels like a case for a polymorphic association. Where I'm feeling confused is what the `has_one` model (user, experience, job post) looks like. Do they have one? They shouldn't have many.

This is a work in progress, so there isn't much more code-wise I can really add. But if there are any areas where I can share more or elaborate, I'm happy to.

Comment: It may seem counter intuitive, but in your first case a User does indeed belong to a Pronoun on an optional basis as you've setup.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. Agreed it seems counter-intuitive, but it must just be the rails way. It's how I would design it but not how I'd name the associations.

Comment: You're asking two very different questions here. Split them up and ask each one seperately. No one like to answer "forked" questions as they lead to an endless scope creep via comments - aka feeding the help vamplire.

Comment: And as to the `has_one` vs `belongs_to` - forget about the semantics which is quite confusing and just focus on what the methods do. Thats what everyone (including myself at one point) gets hung up on. `belongs_to` is what you should be using since this model has a foreign key column that points to the other table. If you think about it this way - every `has_one` or `has_many` always has a `belongs_to` pointing back to it. It should probally be `belongs_to :pronoun` though as assocation names should be singular even if that doesn't quite match up with how its used in English.